# How to reverse the Y axis range in dygraphs (R - shiny)?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to reverse the Y axis scale in dygraphs embedded in a shiny app.

My code -

```
  output$rainintensity <- renderDygraph({
    withProgress(message = 'Loading graphs',{
      dygraph(rain_data(), group = "sync") %>%
        dyAxis("y", "Rainfall intensity  (Inches/Hr)", valueRange = c(NULL, 0)) %>%
        dySeries(input$rainguage,label="Rainfall intensity  (Inches/Hr)") %>%
        dyOptions(includeZero = TRUE, retainDateWindow = TRUE, colors = "blue", plotter = 
                    "function barChartPlotter(e) {
                var ctx = e.drawingContext;
                var points = e.points;
                var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);  // see     http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomYCoord

                // This should really be based on the minimum gap
                var bar_width = 2/3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
                ctx.fillStyle = e.color;

                // Do the actual plotting.
                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var p = points[i];
                var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

                ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
                ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
                }
  }")
    })
  })
```

I get the following output graph -

[image]

It works when I set a definite valueRange as following:

```
output$rainintensity <- renderDygraph({
    withProgress(message = 'Loading graphs',{
      dygraph(rain_data(), group = "sync") %>%
        dyAxis("y", "Rainfall intensity  (Inches/Hr)", valueRange = c(1, 0)) %>%
        dySeries(input$rainguage,label="Rainfall intensity  (Inches/Hr)") %>%
        dyOptions(includeZero = TRUE, retainDateWindow = TRUE, colors = "blue", plotter = 
                    "function barChartPlotter(e) {
                var ctx = e.drawingContext;
                var points = e.points;
                var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);  // see     http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomYCoord

                // This should really be based on the minimum gap
                var bar_width = 2/3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
                ctx.fillStyle = e.color;

                // Do the actual plotting.
                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var p = points[i];
                var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

                ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
                ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
                }
  }")
    })
  })
```

Result -

[image]

Is there any way I can reverse the Y axis range without setting a definite valueRange on the Y axis?

I tried giving a reactive upper bound in the valueRange based on zooming. sort of like this - `valueRange = c(max(react_rain_data()*1.10, na.rm = TRUE), 0)` but it re renders the graphs every time the user zooms in.

Note - According to the [documentation for dyAxis fucnction](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dygraphs/versions/1.1.1.4/topics/dyAxis) :

> valueRange: Explicitly set the vertical range of the graph to c(low, high). This may be set on a per-axis basis to define each y-axis separately. If either limit is unspecified, it will be calculated automatically (e.g. c(NULL, 30) to automatically calculate just the lower bound).

Thanks!